# date regexep validator 3 formats : dd/mm/yyyy mm/yyyy and yyyy

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a date regexp validator who valide date in the followed formats :

- dd/mm/yyyy
- mm/yyyy
- yyyy
  and any date with year lower than 1600 should be invalid

must be valid :

> 24/01/2015 ,
>   01/01/2000 , 
>   01/2000 ,
>   2000 , 
>   1600 ,

must be invalid :

> 1599 , 
>   12/1599 ,
>   31/12/1599 ,

I made this but it not work for `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/yyyy`

```
 ^(1[6-9][0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})(?:[-\/](0[1-9]|1[0-2]))?(?:[-\/](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-\/](0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/e_L6q7R0D8iHfZ_0)

any idea how to fix this ? 
thx

Comment: Is `24/11/1599` valid or invalid?

Comment: any date with year lower than 1600 should be invalid tjx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that you won't be able to easily express the most complex checks for date with a regular expression, for example :

- is 31 a valid day for the month?
- is 29/02 a valid date for the year?

That said, the following regular expression should answer your specification :

```
(?:(?:(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])/)?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/)?(1[6-9]\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3})
```

The first group will correspond to the day part, the second to the months and the third to the year.

Comment: yes of course it cannot valide this kind of rules but no problem. your regges is good are far simpler than mine thanks

Comment: @AlainIb I just updated it, it previously matched `00/00/xxxx`

Comment: i found a little bug . it valid '26/1985' (DD/YYYY) 
this can fix maybe

Comment: (?:(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])/(?:(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/))??(?:(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/)?(1[6-9]\d{2}|2\d{3})

Comment: Just fixed it, I made it so the day part can't match if there is no month part